# Expo EAS not resolving sentry-expo. Are dependencies cached?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've joined the EAS preview, and I'm having problem when building my app. The build works perfectly with the classic build system. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: the build steps that are failing]

I think that EAS is caching the dependencies, but I'm not sure if this is the problem or how to clear their cache.

The first time I built the app, the process was slighty different:

[image: the steps of the build process in the first build]

As you can see, there is a "Install dependencies" step that isn't in the newer builds. That error of the install dependencies is already fixed.

I've `sentry-expo` in my package.json and in my `app.config.js` I have `plugins: ["sentry-expo"],`

I've also tried adding `"cache": {"disabled": true}` to the android build config with no success.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FabricioG Where you able to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a dependency management issue. In my case I was attempting to use yarn "pnp" which which doesn't support react-native at this time to my knowledge. I reverted that and was able to get past this.

My .gitignore

```
# yarn berry
.pnp.*
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
```

My .yarnrc.yml

```
yarnPath: '.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs'
nodeLinker: 'node-modules'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install dependencies

`npm i sentry-expo -s`

`yarn add sentry-expo`

And rebuild `eas build --platform ios --profile preview`

This is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can run `npm i` before sending the build over to expo.

A side benefit of this is that it catches any library issues in your controlled CI environment rather than from expo